# UISearchbar on KeyPress Trigger a Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uisearchbar

How do I pass the input and trigger the following method whenever user key in a character at my search bar? Something like a keyup function.

```
- (void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {

    sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:@"Search"];
    sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:txtSearch.text];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sRefresh];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [refresh endRefreshing];

}
```

## ANSWER

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)txtGym textDidChange:(NSString*)searchText;
  {
     [self handleRefresh:nil];
  }
```

Comment: Have you used  UISearchBarDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  UISearchBarDelegate and call your desire function when you want to tigger and change searchActive status according to your status.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}
```